# How to retrieve data for a precise answer and subsequent answers

Tags: survey-list

Ok so let me explain...at the moment I am trying to make a training survey where for instance I state:

Who did you have as a Trainer? 
Trainer A,
Trainer B

In what country did you attend training?
A,
B,
C,

And then more generic questions....

I want to then somehow retrieve data on participants that marked Trainer A and in Country C... and their answers to all other questions in the particular survey. Basically so I can provide trainers with an overview on their performance.

I know one result

Is this at all possible?

Look forward to your reply.

Cheers,

Heidi

Answer (score 0):

A. Create a filtered view for each combination you care about on the list
 B. Export the data to excel, then filter.